# KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT: Is there a reason why field vkCode is 32-bit unsigned DWORD?

Tags: winapi

From [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-kbdllhookstruct), `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT` is defined as:

```
typedef struct tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT {
  DWORD     vkCode;
  DWORD     scanCode;
  DWORD     flags;
  DWORD     time;
  ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;
} KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT, *LPKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT, *PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
```

Field `vkCode` has type `DWORD`.  According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-kbdllhookstruct) `DWORD` is defined as `A 32-bit unsigned integer.`

However, the field docs say: `The code must be a value in the range 1 to 254.`

Is there an undocumented purpose for the additional 3 bytes of data in this field?  Or is this either (a) byte alignment concerns or (b) future expansion of virtual key codes?

Comment: Seems that packing would be the most likely reason; using just a `char`-sized variable would make the structure dependent on packing settings and then, if the caller has different packing than the receiver, it would break the code. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: Same applies to scanCode and flags, currently they all fit in a BYTE.  Whether they'll still fit 50 years from now is hard to guess.  Keeping the struct small is not important.

Comment: @AdrianMole Both caller and implementation use the same *WinUser.h* header, so different structure packing cannot happen (at least not without breaking everything else, like the `ACCEL` structure).

Comment: @AdrianMole Your comment is a good answers.  I am happy to give credit if you post an answer.  Thank you for the good feedback.

Comment: @HansPassant Your comment is a good answers.  I am happy to give credit if you post an answer.  Thank you for the good feedback.  (Sorry to repeat: I am only allowed to @-tag one person per comment!)